# JSON Schema Multiple Affiliations

Tags: json, seo, schema

I have an attorney that has multiple affiliations that I want to mark up with JSON schema. What is the best way to do this?...

Option #1:

```
"affiliation": "Example 1, Example 2",
```

Option #2

```
"affiliation": "Example 1",
"affiliation": "Example 2",
```

Or, is there another way to do this that I haven't considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
"affiliations":[ "Example 1", "Example 2", "Example 3" ]
```